# Levels function returning NULL

Tags: r, null, levels

I'm hoping this is an easy fix.  Whenever I run levels(df) am I given a NULL output.  This isn't specific to my data frame as it occurs with any set of data that I use.  I am thinking that there may be an issue with one of my packages.  Has anyone run into this or know of a fix?  Thanks

Comment: `levels` tells you the levels of a factor. It does not directly apply to data frames

Comment: `levels` looks at the `levels` attribute of an object. `data.frames` doesn't necessarily have one, hence the `NULL` output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only run `levels` on a factor vector, not on a data frame.

Example below

```
> df <- data.frame(a = factor(c('a','b','c'), levels = c('a','b','c','d','e')),
+                  b = factor(c('a','b','c')), 
+                  c = factor(c('a','a','c')))
> levels(df)
NULL
```

To see the level of every column in your data frame, you can use `lapply`

```
> lapply(df, levels)
$a
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

$b
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$c
[1] "a" "c"
```

If you want the levels of a specific column, you can specify that instead:

```
> levels(df[, 2])
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

---

EDIT: To answer question below on why `apply(df, 2, levels)` returns `NULL`.

Note the following from the documentation for `apply()`:

> In all cases the result is coerced by as.vector to one of the basic
>   vector types before the dimensions are set, so that (for example)
>   factor results will be coerced to a character array.

You can see this behavior when you try to take the class, and try a few other functions.

```
> apply(df, 2, levels)
NULL
> apply(df, 2, class)
          a           b           c 
"character" "character" "character" 
> apply(df, 2, function(i) levels(i))
NULL
> apply(df, 2, function(i) levels(factor(i)))
$`a`
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$b
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$c
[1] "a" "c"
```

Note that even though we can force `apply()` to treat the columns as factors, we lose the prior ordering/levels that were set for `df` when it was originally created (see column `` `a` ``). This is because it has been coerced into a character vector.

Comment: Any idea why `apply(df,2,levels)` also returns `NULL`?

Answer (score 18):

When initializing a dataframe, pass stringsAsFactors = T in the initialization

eg. `dataFrame <- read.csv(file.choose(), stringsAsFactors=T)`

this makes R treat the string values as factors.
Hope it helped

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the data frame was read, it is possible that the columns or arrays may not be processed as factors (conveniently taken as input by levels). Hence a simple fix is:

```
levels(as.factor(df$COLUMN_of_choice))
```